# option to dismiss unanswered questions from my tags view

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions, tag-watching

I really enjoy spending time attempting to help others on Stack Overflow. However, I have seen the same list of questions in my Unanswered > My Tags view for several months. I have reviewed those questions and I can't provide any input. It would be nice to be able to "dismiss" those and allow others to filter into view.